# redis key after redis server shutdown and restart not available

Tags: redis

To add keys to redis I did the following via the redis CLI:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
1) "key1"
2) "key2"
3) "key3"
127.0.0.1:6379> SET name "rahul"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
1) "key1"
2) "name"
3) "key2"
4) "key3"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

To validate the persistence of the data in my redis data store, I re-started the server, upon checking the keys, I found few keys to be missing :

```
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
1) "key3"
2) "key2"
3) "key1"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Are there any specific naming conventions for redis keys. I was using a Windows system. Any idea of what has gone wrong. TIA.

Answer (score 4):

If you do a graceful shutdown values will be written to disk before the service is shutdown. If it's a abrupt shutdown or power failure values will be lost. For that you can enable persistance (RDB or AOF). By default redis follows RDB snapshotting, by default it takes snapshot based on three conditions
1) atleast one keys changed for 15 mins.
2) atleast ten keys changed for 5 mins.
3) atleast 10,000 keys changed for 1 min.

You can change these values in redis.conf file under SNAPSHOTTING.

Try reading the redis.conf file fully, it will give you more detailed explanations.